# path of a .txt file in java

Tags: java, file, path

I work with NetBeans IDE an I have a .txt file saved in src/myapp folder. If I run from the IDE, this recognise my

```
File file=new File("src/myapp/mytext.txt");
```

But if I build the jar file and double click it or launch it from command line I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\myapp\mytext.txt
```

I could insert absolute path, but how can I run my jar independently by the position of my project in the computer?

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the file path indepently of its position with the following:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
String path = classLoader.getResource("mytext.txt").toString();
```

Comment: This is not independent of its positioning. This assumes it is in the classpath, which if running from a jar file will only include the contents of the jar file.

Comment: That is true. Because of the file path I have assumed that it is in the classpath, so using this it is possible to run the jar without depending on the position of the project in the computer.

Comment: Yes, it isn't clear if the OP is packaging the file inside the Jar (I would expect it to be in a resources folder though) or he is just expecting to find it outside in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Java is expecting to find the file relative to your working directory. So by hardcoding the file in `src/myapp/mytext.txt` you are expecting the user of your application to have the 
file under the same folder structure.

If you are expecting the file to be at the same level of your jar file, you can just use `./mytext.txt`. Do not put your `mytext.txt` under the `src` in your project. That is for sources you want to compile and/or bundle inside your jar file. In NetBeans move it outside the `/src` folder, that way when you run the program from your IDE or when you run it externally from your Jar file you find the file at the same level.

If you want the user to be able to specify the location himself of the file, you can also read the command line arguments (the arguments to your `public static void main(String[] args)`).

Comment: How can I put it outside src from NetBeans? There are no folders outside "Source Packages".

Comment: What is the absolute path of your project? Your `src` is somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such problem

```
File file=new File("./src/myapp/mytext.txt");
```

Comment: Still get  java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\src\myapp\mytext.txt if I run externally